# calc() function inside another calc() in CSS

Tags: css, css-calc

How do I use a CSS calc function inside another CSS calc function? According to this [post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) it is possible but there is no example of that.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> It is possible to use calc() inside another calc().

An example:

```
div{
  width: calc(100% - (1% + 30px));/* calc(1% + 30px) is nested inside calc()*/
}
div p{
  width: calc(100% - 30px);/*100% is total width of the div*/
}
```

---

Update on [nested calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Nested_calc()_with_CSS_Variables) with css variables:

```
.foo {
  --widthA: 100px;
  --widthB: calc(var(--widthA) / 2);
  --widthC: calc(var(--widthB) / 2);
  width: var(--widthC);
}
```

> After all variables are expanded, widthC's value will be calc( calc( 100px / 2) / 2), then when it's assigned to .foo's width property, all inner calc()s (no matter how deeply nested) **will be flattened to just parentheses**, so the width property's value will be eventually calc( ( 100px / 2) / 2), i.e. 25px. In short: a calc() inside of a calc() is identical to just parentheses.

So, the current spec as well proves this using parentheses inside calc() is nested calc.

Learn more about css variables [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

Comment: Thats for the reply . I see you are using just one calc function. My question was how to use one calc Inside another calc function.

Comment: Basically you can not use calc inside a calc, so Bhojendra Rauniyar's solution is do calc separately and save it in css variable. Finally you can get what you want.

Answer (score 67):

I'm one of the editors of the Values & Units spec, which defines calc().

calc() *should* be nestable inside of calc().  There was an oversight in the grammar/definitions for a while that *technically* didn't allow it, but I recently fixed that.  Implementations haven't caught up yet, to my knowledge (tho it looks like Chrome 51 and Firefox 48 will have this fixed, woo!).

That said, there is *zero reason* to nest calc() expressions normally - they're *exactly identical* to just using parentheses.  The only reason to do it at all is when using custom properties/variables.

Comment: Hey Tab!  Do note that about the time you wrote this, the fix for this landed in Blink.  It was also fixed in Gecko before that.  I guess you were involved with both fixes, anyway thanks for that, I needed it (for custom properties ;)).  So fix will be in Chromium 51, Opera 38 and Firefox 48.

Comment: can you perhaps give an example? eg calc( 1 + (2 / 3))

Comment: Here's a use case, although you might not like it.  I'm using styled components, and it's convenient to define some border width based off a value in a table somewhere.  I have another property based off this property, and another off this one.  So I have `w === '2px'` (say), and `w_ === \`calc(${w} * 2)\``, and `w__ === \`calc(${w_} * 2\``.  This is somewhat more contrived than the actual code, but it's the basic idea.

Comment: Here's an example that would require a nested calc(): 
`width: calc(100vw - calc(var(--page-margin) * 2))`

Comment: That does not require nested calc, just parentheses: `calc(100vw - (var(--page-margin) * 2))`.

Answer (score 14):

The reference you quoted is admittedly a bit confusing.

It is ***not*** possible to use a `calc` function inside another `calc`.

From the specs here: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#calc-notation

> ...Components of a calc() expression can be literal values, attr() or
>   calc() expressions, or  values..

You can have `calc` expression inside the expressions, but not the `calc()` function itself.

And an example is given in that ref for nested expressions:

```
width: calc(100%/3 - 2*1em - 2*1px);
```

And also for multiple `calc` for multiple properties:

```
margin: calc(1rem - 2px) calc(1rem - 1px);
```

The syntax from the spec above:

> The syntax of a calc() function is:
>
> ```
> <calc()> = calc( <calc-sum> ) 
> <calc-sum> = <calc-product> [ [ '+' | '-' ] <calc-product> ]* 
> <calc-product> = <calc-value> [ '*' <calc-value> | '/' <number> ]* 
> <calc-value> = <number> | <dimension> | <percentage> | ( <calc-sum> )
> ```
>
> Where a <dimension> is a dimension.
>
> In addition, whitespace is required on both sides of the + and -
>   operators. (The * and / operaters can be used without whitespace
>   around them.)
>
> UAs must support calc() expressions of at least 20 terms, where each
>   NUMBER, DIMENSION, or PERCENTAGE is a term. If a calc() expression
>   contains more than the supported number of terms, it must be treated
>   as if it were invalid.

.

Comment: I think it's just out of date. Last year's revision of the grammar suggested that you could in fact nest `calc()` function calls: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-syntax Of course, that was last year. I don't know if it was ever implemented that way.

Comment: @BoltClock: The spec you linked is of 30-Jul-2013. The spec which I linked to is the "dev" of 19-Dec-2014. So, I think the correct reference would be to the spec you linked to. But, even that does not say that `calc` can be nested. Maybe I am not looking hard!

Comment: You can see the `calc` production nested within another production... that is nested within the `calc` production. Anyway, it turns out that implementations do follow what's in the ED so I think they just changed the spec to match.

Comment: @BoltClock: Hmmm.. yes that is confusing because it says *Components of a ‘calc()’ expression can be literal values, ‘attr()’ or ‘calc()’ expressions, or <percentage> values that resolve to one of the preceding types* but later in the document it uses *calc* as nested production: *unit    : [ NUMBER | DIMENSION | PERCENTAGE | "(" S* sum S* ")" | calc | attr ]*.. Well, I think I should update the answer. Thank you indeed for pointing it out.

Comment: Yup, it was just an oversight in the grammar. Source: I'm the spec editor, and I recently fixed this.

Comment: Looks like Internet Explorer 11 doesn't support nested calcs e.g. calc(((100% - calc((80 / 100) * (100% + 17px))) / 2) + 17px / 2).. Chrome doesn't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks, the comment about required spaces around + and - operators solved my issues ;)