# How to nest calc-variables within other calc-variables in Sass?

Tags: css, sass, css-calc

How can I link a variable with an calc-value in another variable?

What I do:

```
$height:                25px;
$size:                  calc(#{$height} - 10px);
$margin:                calc(#{$radiosize} /4);
$padding:               calc(#{$radiosize} *2);
```

What happens:

```
$height:                25px;
$size:                  15px;
$margin:                /*does not work*/;
$padding:               /*does not work*/;
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNXpOV)

Comment: What does not work? Did you define the value for the variables inside calc? AFAIK this works fine in SASSmeister.

Comment: the compiler does not set margin and padding ("invalid operands for multiplication")... this works fine in SASSmeister, i know. But intelliJ says no... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function inside another calc().

**Current compiled CSS:**

```
margin: calc(calc(25px - 10px) /4); /* Incorrect syntax */
padding: calc(calc(25px - 10px) *2); /* Incorrect syntax */
```

**Solution:**

Calculate the size variable directly.

```
$size: $height - 10px;
```

[**Forked Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Manojkr/pen/gawowy)

Comment: You can now nest `calc()` inside another `calc()`. The spec has been changed, and browsers are catching up. Your example works in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Illya. Good work, W3C team! :)

Comment: @GurebuBokofu They are incompatible. So adjust the other values based on the consistent unit. This is not a generic solution but works for his use case.

Comment: @ManojKumar, "This is not a generic solution" - why? I suppose in general case we need to reduce all parameters so single unit.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu I am saying the answer is not a generic solution but the comment is.

Comment: @ManojKumar, Oh, I am sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible to ship a calc() into an other calc(). Unfortunately with a little Hack:

```
$var1: 3px;
$var2: 5px;

$innerCalc: '(#{$var1} + #{$var2})';
$actualCalc: calc(#{$innerCalc} / 2); //4px
```

This will do the trick. 
It simply put all (incl. Brackets) into your calc, but is still able to resolve the variables. Enjoy. :)

P.S. NEVER forget the whitespaces before and after every operator!

Comment: Whitespaces are not needed after every operator, only some.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, given the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNXpOV) you provided in the comments, you don't need to use `calc()`. As a rule of thumb, use `calc()` when you want to mix units, e.g. subtracting a `px` value from a `%`.

It seems that you are manipulating `px` values either (1) with other `px`, or (2) with unitless numbers, so there is no need to use `calc()`:

```
$height:                25px;
$size:                  $height - 10px;
$margin:                $size / 4;
$padding:               $size * 2;
```

Here's the Codepen: https://codepen.io/imoskvin/pen/gXdMgR

---

However, to answer your actual question: you *can* now nest `calc()` inside other `calc()`'s!

It seems this was the original intent, and the spec has been updated accordingly. Browsers are catching up: your original [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNXpOV) now works as intended in Chrome and Firefox.

For more details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36414853/1943591) from one of the spec editors.