# css calc with calculated variables

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, calc

i'm working on a project where the main content is calculated as:

> $content-height: calc(100vh - 50px - 62px);

inside the content I have a table which height is calculated as:

`height: calc(#{$content-height} - 62px - 50px/2 - 66.1px);`

in Chrome the output is:

`height: calc(calc(100vh - 50px - 62px) - 62px - 50px/2 - 66.1px);`

and it works fine.

in Internet explorer (11) this doesn't work. 
when i remove the inner `calc` like:
`height: calc((100vh - 50px - 62px) - 62px - 50px/2 - 66.1px);`

it works fine.

iv'e searched the web for answers for this topic but found none.
any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can't have a calc inside a calc like that ... the inner _calc_ word needs to go. Why it works in Chrome I can't say though the specs says no

Comment: In general, it is possible to lay things out as you want them without doing this type of manual calculation. If you show more of your HTML, perhaps people could comment as to how.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this *should* have worked (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36414853/1869660), but since it doesn't, you can make a SASS function to help creating valid `calc` expressions:

```
//https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/str-replace-function/
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
    $index: str-index($string, $search);
    @if $index {
        @return
            str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + 
            $replace + 
            //Recursively replace the rest of the string:
            str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
    }
    @return $string;
}

@function calced($expressions...) {
    $result: "";
    @each $x in $expressions {
        @if (str-length($result) > 0) {
            $result: $result + " + ";
        }
        $result: $result + str-replace(#{$x}, "calc", "");
    }
    $result: str-replace($result, "+ -", "- ");
    @return unquote("calc(" + $result + ")");
}
```

Usage:

```
$content-height: calc(100vh - 50px - 62px);
//..or $content-height: calced(100vh ,-50px ,-62px);

.test {
    height: calced($content-height/2, -60px, 20%, "-20vh/3");
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/NbZLqd?editors=0100